# ^M behind operating system version?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, operating-system

I am currently writing a perl script to extract data from a log file and create statements using the data in a new file.

In this new file, one particular data that I've extracted and used here is the operating system's version. It shows `Windows XP Service Pack 3^M`. I noticed this `^M` only appears when I edit using **vi**. When I display the contents of the file normally using command prompt or PuTTy with `more`, it only shows `Windows XP Service Pack 3`.

Can anyone explain or refer to me a link on why there's an `^M`? I've found nothing on Google search. All I know is that it has something to do between Windows and Unix or Linux operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vi` and familiars (you're probably actually using `vim`) display the the return character as `^M`. Since line endings in unix and windows are different, you get this displayed instead of an actual line break.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the fast answer. Will accept your answer soon once I the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

DOS and Unix (and Mac?) have different "newline" conventions. The `vi` program is doing the correct thing.  The `more` program is too.  It is a pager and is hiding this from you.

Using the perl `chomp()` function, it should clean up any EOL weirdness.